# Authorizing a user based on claims when using a reference token

Tags: authorization, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I am using a reference token to get the users claims as the JWT token was too long. This works fine from a client controller:

```
var introspectionClient = new IntrospectionClient(
    "http://localhost:5000/connect/introspect",
    "api1",
    "secret");

var response = await introspectionClient.SendAsync(
    new IntrospectionRequest { Token = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token") });

ViewBag.Json = Json(response.Json).Value;
return View("json");
```

As I can use `HttpContext` to retrieve the access token and exchange it for the users claims at the introspection endpoint.

However from the authorization handler I cannot access the `HttpContext` to get the access token and the `AuthorizationHandlerContext`only contains claims from the id token.

I'm open to all suggestions but it does feel like there should be a way to get the access token in the authorization handler but i could well be wrong.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know if this is the way you should do it. But to answer your question, you can inject the context like this:

```
//using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;

public class MyAuthorizationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<MyRequirement>
{
    private IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public MyAuthorizationHandler(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    protected async override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, MyRequirement requirement)
    {
        var token = await _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
    }
}
```

You will need to make `HandleRequirementAsync` async. You don't have to add IHttpContextAccessor in startup to the services. This is already done by Identity.

Comment: Thank you for this. Would you recommend doing this another way then?

Comment: I can imagine that you want to contact the server as minimal as possible. So you may want to add a scoped service that does this once per request and I would add some caching as well to prevent contact on every request.

Comment: OK. So what you're saying is that this is an acceptable solution from a security standpoint but needs more work to reduce the number of calls to the server?

Comment: I've never used Reference Tokens, but from what I understand the Introspection endpoint is automatically called for you (or you may need to set the backchannel in the options). You add the line `client.AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Reference;` and in Startup you can set the options `EnableCaching` and `CacheDuration`.

Comment: I have done these things. And yes, I am fairly sure that the docs said that the middle ware is smart enough to distinguish between the different access token types and act accordingly. Anyway, thank you for your help, I am seeing the claims come through now.